# Given an object ,how can I know its class in perl?

Tags: perl

I need this info to decide which of the classes with a specific method is being called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the [ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) builtin to determine the reference type or class of a variable:

```
my $obj = bless [] => 'Some::Class';

print ref($obj), "\n";  # 'Some::Class';
```

More detail can be found with `Scalar::Util`'s `reftype` (always returns the container type) and `blessed` (always returns the class name) subroutines.

Answer (score 8):

`ref` will usually work fine but `blessed` in [Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar%3a%3aUtil) may be a better choice. It will return `undef` for plain references that aren't blessed into a package for example.

Answer (score 0):

`ref($obj)` will do the job for you.